# Not able to post data on aws http api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In my lambda function when i return this

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return json.dumps("{'result':'abcde'}")
```

it is returning the expected result, but when i return this

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return event["payloadData"]
```

It gave "message": "Internal Server Error"
I am posting data using postman

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://sampleurl.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sms' \
--form 'payloadData="9876543210"'
```

my cors header from aws

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
*

Access-Control-Allow-Headers
*

Access-Control-Allow-Methods
POST

OPTIONS
*
```

cloudwatch log

```
{
    "requestId": "Be7tojFFPHcEMQg=",
    "ip": "157.39.109.241",
    "requestTime": "25/Jun/2021:13:26:34 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "routeKey": "POST /sms",
    "status": "500",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "35"
}
```

Comment: Inspect the cloudwatch logs, add debug print statements, etc. to see that `event` does not contain `payloadData` on the top level.

Comment: @luk2302 the log is added

Comment: That is not the lambda log that is the log of the gateway. And I already know what the lambda log will contain: a KeyError for the reason given in the first comment

Comment: @luk2302 it is the keyError as you said but why i am not able to post data

Comment: You are able to - but the data is far more deeply nested within the event, log the event ant try to find your data

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the post data but it was not in event["payloadData"]. 
It was inside event["body"] which is base64 encoded.
So i use this to get the posted data

```
base64.b64decode(str(event["body"])).decode('utf-8')
```